# How to add class inside the dropdown-option into react-dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I Install the react-dropdown    https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown?activeTab=readme.
I want to add my class directly to dropdown-option [image]

App.js

```
    import './App.css';
    import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
    import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
    import { Option } from 'react-dropdown';
    
    
    const reporTypes = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.report.options.types);
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Dropdown
                            onChange={handleTypeChange}
                            options={reporTypes} value={selectedType} className='mh-select-container' controlClassName='mh-dropdown mh-dropdown-rounded' menuClassName='mh-dropdown-content' />
        </div>
      );
    }

export default App;
```

How can I add this?

[image]

Comment: Try adding `baseClassName` if that property exist. I can see that in the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the documentation

```
//option 1: for static options
const reporTypes = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two', className: 'myOptionClassName' },
]

//option 2: mapping from selector
const reporTypes = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.report.options.types?.map(type => ({ ...type, className: 'myOptionClassName'  }));

 // Option 3: mapping use useMemo
 const reporTypes = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.report.options.types);

  const mappedReportTypes = useMemo(() => {

     return reporTypes?.map(type => ({ ...type, className: 'myOptionClassName'  }))

  }, [reporTypes ])

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dropdown  options={reporTypes} placeholder="Select an option" className='mh-class' controlClassName='myControlClassName' menuClassName='myMenuClassName' arrowClassName='myarrow'/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I would suggest using the [library with more rating](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) as it could have lesser bugs and will handle more use cases

Comment: When the option comes dynamically then how we can add a class to it? @Azzy

Comment: @AnjaliPatel, if you need to add the same class to all options, it should be possible to do it when you get the response, or when you get them as props, please include some code so that I can try to come up with a solution

Comment: here I edit the code of react js for data that comes from reporTypes when I do console.log(reporTypes) and then data fetch in the console. see the above image. @Azzy

Comment: @AnjaliPatel I updated the answer, Hope it helps you to solve the problem and consider making it as answered if it helps you, Cheers

Comment: Welcome @AnjaliPatel, glad it  helped you out

Comment: hey, class not added in dropdown option after import the import { Option } from 'react-dropdown'; in file. code update in above. - @Azzy

Comment: That is to customize the display of the options, its given in the docs of a [different library](https://react-select.com/components), then what is given in the question, there is [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dxz03y?module=/example.tsx) example showing is use, hope it helps